# How to create attractive windows in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe

I am developing a desktop application using Adobe AIR 2.2 on windows 7 OS. By default the style of the window is similar to the windows OS theme. I want to create stylish title bar similar to iTunes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these:

http://www.graviti.tv/blog/?p=45

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/creating-custom-chrome-in-adobe-air-using-flex/

Good luck,
Rob